# Monitor goes blank after 30 minutes. No keyboard or mouse are attatched, but computer is controlled over SSH

Tags: ssh, display, suspend, x-server

Currently trying to set up a media server which I can control with my laptop or phone. After looking at all the options I decided upon using SSH to start mplayer in fullscreen. Everything is working fine. Until 30 minutes in when the monitor suspends. I can make the monitor wake up from suspension with the xset -dpms, but the screen stays black, until I plug in a peripheral and do some for of input.

Comment: turn off power management / sleep for the monitor, surely ? How to do that depends on the UI